# How to get VoiceOver screen reader to work with radio buttons, to say proper number of choices

Tags: radio-button, voiceover, screen-readers

When using VoiceOver, Apple's screen reader for iPad, on the following radio button group, it reads them as, **"Nominal, radio button, unchecked 1 of 1"**. I want it to read it as, **"Nominal, radio button, unchecked 1 of 3"**, to reflect the proper number of choices.

```css
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
input.radio-float {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
label.radio-float {
  max-width: 24em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: maroon;
}
span.radio-float {
  max-width: 24em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  color: gray;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 form-inline">
  <fieldset id="FilterLevel">
    <legend>Please choose a filter level</legend>
    <input class="radio-float" id="FilterLow" name="FilterLevel" required="required" type="radio" value="LOW">
    <label for="FilterLow" class="radio-float">Nominal:</label>
    <br>
    <span class="radio-float">This level will catch most, but not all incoming spam. It is the safest selection if you are concerned about legitimate mail being inadvertently intercepted.</span>
    <br>

    <input checked="checked" class="radio-float" id="FilterMedium" name="FilterLevel" type="radio" value="MEDIUM">
    <label for="FilterMedium" class="radio-float">Aggressive:</label>
    <br>
    <span class="radio-float">More spam will be caught. There is a slight chance that legitimate mail may be blocked.</span>
    <br>

    <input class="radio-float" id="FilterHigh" name="FilterLevel" type="radio" value="HIGH">
    <label for="FilterHigh" class="radio-float">Very Aggressive:</label>
    <br>
    <span class="radio-float">This level should catch almost all spam. However, there is an increased risk that legitimate mail may be blocked. Use with care.</span>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

The problem is that everything I try to keep the `<span class="radio-float">` indented seem to break VoiceOver's ability to identify the number of options in the radio group.

- Any ideas on what causes VoiceOver to go from *"1 of 1"* to *"1 of 3"*?
- For bonus points, can you think of a way to make VoiceOver happy and keep the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the "display: block". When VoiceOver hits this, it's seeing it as essentially a "wall", and doesn't look past it to detect that there are other radio buttons in the group. Changing this to "display: inline-block" however remedies this, and still allows you to apply your padding/margin to the left of the description.

Comment: Looks like I got it to work with what you suggested https://jsfiddle.net/EricOP/g01pwdum/ Thanks man. So crazy that `display: block;` freezes VoiceOver in its tracks.